# Is there a way to hide the private members of a class, to the clients of that class?

Tags: c++, class, declaration

The users of a class need not see the private members of that class. Those members may introduce new types the users should not be aware of, requiring #include of files to declare those types. I would like to get rid of these #include. I would prefer declaring these private members of the class, in a separate .hpp file that is seen only by the implementation of the class.
Is there a way doing this ?

I'm afraid it is not possible as the client class has probably to know the size of an instance of that class, then must have access to its full declaration. This unfortunately adds useless dependances.

Comment: TLDR: Pass your objects by interface pointer with virtual methods, not as concrete instances. I can elaborate if that doesn't make sense. Your clients don't get direct pointers to your concrete class. They get a pointer to the pure virtual class it inherits from.

Comment: It's called "pimpl" or [pointer to implementation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl) pattern.

Answer (score 3):

You would usually use the [pimpl idiom](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl) for this:

```cpp
// --------------------
// interface (widget.h)
class widget
{
    widget();
    void exampleFunction();
private:
    struct impl;
    std::unique_ptr<impl> pImpl;
};
 
// ---------------------------
// implementation (widget.cpp)
struct widget::impl
{
    // implementation details
    int exampleMember;
};

widget::widget() : pImpl(std::make_unique<widget::impl>()){}

void widget::exampleFunction() {
   pImpl->exampleMember++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple pattern is this.

```
// IFoo.h
#pragma once
class IFoo
{
public:
   virtual void DoSomethingImportant() = 0;
   virtual void DoSomethingElse() = 0;
};

-----------------------
// Foo.h
#pragma once
#include "IFoo.h"
#include "MessyHeaderFilesThatPullIntooMuch.h"
class Foo : public IFoo
{
private:
   ComplexStructure _internals;  // stuff you don't want clients to know abouve
   int _x;
   int _y;
public:
   virtual void DoSomethingImportant() override;
   virtual void DoSomethingElse() override;
};

-----------------------
// Foo.cpp
#include "Foo.h"
void Foo::DoSomethingImportant() {Your code goes here}
void Foo::DoSomethingElse() {Your code goes here}

-----------------------
// FooFactory.h
#pragma once
#include <IFoo.h>
IFoo* CreateFoo();

-----------------------
// FooFactory.cpp
#include <FooFactory.h>
#include <Foo.h>
IFoo* CreateFoo()
{
    return new Foo();
}
```

Then the clients who want to get at an instance of "Foo" just need to `#include "FooFactory.h"` to obtain a new instance of Foo via the IFoo interface pointer. And they never have to see the messy internals of Foo or take a dependency on the additional header files Foo needs. They get back just the public interface of Foo that hides all the internals.